# jsf sessionbean has different values for setter and getter

Tags: jsf-2

In a jsf(Mojarra 2.1)-application I call  a  boolean value from the sessionbean below.
Everything works fine, until I make a logout with session.invalidate and a new login. 
After the new login, the values of detailView are different for getter and setter. That means:

- The setter method is called and the value of detailView is set to
  true.
- After that, the getter method is called, and on client side  for
  detailView the value „false“ is received !!

You can see this also by these ouputlines:

```
System.out.println("getdetailView:" + detailView + ": " + sessionId )
```

And

```
System.out.println("setdetailView:" + detailView + ": " + sessionId );
```

When I compare the sessionIds of both method calls, we can see that both methods have the same sessionId.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "sessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
…

private boolean detailView = false;
public boolean isDetailView() {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    String sessionId = session.getId();
    System.out.println("getdetailView:" + detailView + ": " + sessionId );

    Return detailView;
}

public void setDetailView(final boolean detailView) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    String sessionId = session.getId();
    System.out.println("setdetailView:" + detailView + ": " + sessionId );
    this.detailView = detailView;
}
```

In jsf, the value is called like this:

```
<p:inputText rendered="#{sessionBean.detailView} value="bla"/>
```

It seems, that getter and setter are bound to different datasources, but how can that be?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sets the value of `detailView`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any getter for `detailView` in the backing bean you must have a getter for it:

```
public boolean getDetailView() {
    //any required code.
    Return detailView;
}
```

**Note** your backing bean is annotated by `@SessionScoped` so it's logic if the fields not be accessible after the session ended if you want it to be alive during application annotate it with `@ApplicationScoped`.

**Also** I see a mistake in the `jst` code, correct it:`<p:inputText rendered="#{sessionBean.detailView}" value="bla"/>` however I'm not sure if it's possible to use `EL` expressions for `render` property of inputText, other thing is try this also with putting codes inside `<form>` tag

Comment: afaik for booleans we have to set "public boolean isDetailView() " as getter, or am I wrong?. Anywhere, I tried the same with getDetailview(), and it shows the same behaviour.

Comment: I think, sessioScoped is correct, because I want to have completely new values after the new login. My problem is, that the new sessionbean seems to work (partly) with the values of the old session. At least, I cannot change the value of detailView in the new sessionbean, because the getter always returns the initial value (false), despite of the fact, that the setter has changed the value properly (as shown in the println).

Comment: in question can you show how you are using it in JSF? I mean can you shw your JSF codes also?